# How to run C# task method on separate thread without using Task.Run()

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have console application where I have 2 steps. *Step1* and *Step2*. I want *Step 1* to run on main thread and *Step 2* on different thread in background, and I am using `C# task object` for the same.

See below code snippet:

```
public static Task PrintCount()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Step 2");

     for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
     {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          Console.WriteLine(i);
     }

     return Task.FromResult(0); 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Task.Run(() => PrintCount());

     Console.WriteLine("Step 1");

     Console.Read();
}
```

This **works perfectly fine** If I run the PrintCount() method using **`Task.Run().`**

**When I use without it like mentioned below, it is running as a synchronous operation.**

```
var taskResult = PrintCount();
```

In this case, the *Step 2* will execute first, complete the iteration of 1000 till the method finish and then it will execute *Step 1*.

The question is-- How would I run Step 2 method **without using Task.Run()** and still I wan to run Step 2 method in async manner on different thread.

**What I do believe is** `PrintCount()` returns the `Task` object and If we don't await it, it will run asynchronously, BUT it is NOT behaving like that.

Would you please suggest how would I run `DoSomehing()` on a different thread using `Task` method without using  Task.Run().

Thanks in advance!

**Updates:**

```
 public static async Task PrintCount()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            Console.WriteLine("Step 2");

            for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
```

This will run on a different thread.

No change in how I calling it.

```
var taskResult = PrintCount();
```

Comment: Well what *is* happening? You've said what works, but you haven't said what happens with your current code. Note that you don't really need the overload that calls a `Func<Task>` - you could change your `PrintCount` method to be a `void` method and then just call `Task.Run((Action) PrintCount);`.

Comment: It's also not at all clear what this has to do with the `asp.net-mvc-4` tag...

Comment: Just to be sure. You want to run Step2 async in another thread without using Task.Run? So maybe with using Task.Factory, Thread or BackgroundWorker?

Comment: So....you want to run a non-IO-bound task but you don't like `Task.Run()` for some reason?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reply. asp.net-mvc-4 added mistakenly. However, my question is that- I don't want to run task using Task.Run() method. What I know is- If method return the task, and If we don't await it, it will run asynchronously. correct? But it is NOT behaving like that.

Comment: As a general rule, if you return a `Task` and you **don't** await it, there is the chance it won't ever run or perhaps not to completion

Comment: But *why* don't you want to use `Task.Run`? That's typically how you start a task. What does `Task.Run` do that you don't like? You say it's "not behaving like that" (asynchronously) but it certainly seems to be for me. What makes you think it isn't? Again, you haven't said exactly what you're observing that you weren't expecting.

Comment: @JonSkeet _MickyD _Mighty: See my updated question. I have added another code snippet. There, I am putting Task.Delay() and mark method as async which still return task. and in that case, it is first execute Step 1 and Step 2 wil be in a different thread...

Comment: @JonSkeet I just simply want to execute task in a different thread just by calling method directly e.g. PrintCount() since it return task. I am executing method with PrintCount**()** and this method return task. So it should execute method in a different thread as I am not awaiting it..correct?

Comment: @DamianT: The task returned by `PrintCount()` is basically irrelevant here. It's the *delegate* that's being executed in a different thread, and that's synchronously calling `PrintCount()`. But there's no need for that extra level of indirection, when you can make `PrintCount` return `void` and just execute that asynchronously as I showed before. You *still* haven't explained why you don't want to use `Task.Run`.

Comment: And yes, when you call `PrintCount()` directly, it will execute synchronously. The fact that it returns a task is irrelevant to that.

Comment: (And yes, you can write an async method instead - that will *start* executing on the same thread, but as you're awaiting `Thread.Delay`, and you're running from a console app which doesn't have a synchronization context, it will end up on a different thread. But it's very unclear to me why you've brought that in... do async methods do everything you want? If so, just use them...) If you're asking whether you can use `async` with C# 4 (given the tag), no you can't - but why not just use a more recent version of C#?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! Now I got that If I call PrintCount() directly, it will execute synchronously regardless whether method return task or not. Well, why I DO NOT wanted to use Task.Run() because I was believing that If a method returns task object and if we don't await, it will run on different thread because we're NOT awaiting for it result. Kind of fire-and-forget. That was my belief. And that was the reason I do not wanted to execute with Task.Run(). Thanks for the help and make it clear to me.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest deleting the question, given that it was based on a mistaken premise.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run C# task method on separate thread without using Task.Run()
>
> Well, why I DO NOT wanted to use Task.Run() because I was believing that If a method returns task object and if we don't await, it will run on different thread because we're NOT awaiting for it result. Kind of fire-and-forget.

If you don't `await` the task returned from `Task.Run`, then yes, it is fire-and-forget. The solution is to `await` the task returned from `Task.Run`:

```
public static void PrintCount()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Step 2");

  for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}

static async Task Steps()
{
  var task = Task.Run(() => PrintCount());

  Console.WriteLine("Step 1");

  await task;
}
```

Your `Main` can look like this, though I generally recommend developers use something other than Console apps for "trying out" async. Because `Main` should block on a task, but in general blocking on async tasks should be avoided:

```
static void Main()
{
  Steps().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first implementation of `PrintCount` is indeed synchronous, because that's how you wrote it.  When you call the method it just starts executing each line of code, hitting the `Thread.Sleep` calls and blocking the thread until they each finish, until finally, at the very end, returning an already completed `Task`.

The way to avoid the use of `Task.Run` is to use *inherently asynchronous operations* for any long running operations.  In your case you don't actually have any long running CPU bound work; your only long running opeartion is waiting for a second.  To do nothing for a fixed period of time you use `Task.Delay`.  So if you replace your usages of `Thread.Sleep(...)` with `await Task.Delay(...)` the operation will become *inherently* asynchronous, and won't' need to use `Task.Run` to do it.

In your second implementation you do demonstrate an appropriate usage of `Task.Delay`, but then after awaiting an asynchronous operation, you just block the thread for a while with `Thread.Sleep` calls.  This is blocking a thread while it does nothing, just like before, but the difference is that the code is running in a thread pool thread because it is after an `await`.  The `await` means that the rest of the method is going to be run at some later point after the awaited `Task` finishes, and the way that's done is to let the current thread continue on and then have a thread pool thread run the rest of the method when it's able to run.  Note that if there was a SynchronizationContext set then that would be used to run the continuation, not a thread pool thread.

Answer (score -1):

The `Task` object created is only a description of a task to be done. The `Task` itself doesn't execute until you schedule it, either by using static `Task.Run()` method or by using `task.Start()` instance method.

Comment: I can also execute it by awaiting it. e.g. await TaskMethod()

Comment: Well you should be `await`ing `Task.Run()` too

Comment: It actually depends on what is the goal. In case step 2 is meant to go in parallel to step 1 there is no need in awaiting. In case step 2 should be completed before step 1 without blocking step 1 thread - awaiting is necessary.

Comment: @DamianT Awaiting a task doesn't execute it.  It simply tells the current method to continue doing work after the `Task` finishes.  It does nothing to start work for the Task.

Comment: Your first sentance is correct, a `Task` is indeed a representation of work to be done.  The rest is just all wrong. You don't use `Task.Run` to execute a `Task`.  `Task.Run` is a method to *create* an already running task that represents executing a method in a thread pool thread (if using the default task scheduler; it may execute it in another way if using a non-default scheduler). `Task.Start` is a method that you shouldn't ever use; there's simply no good reason to ever have a non-started `Task`. In a well written program you typically aren't using *either* method to get a started `Task`.

Comment: _Task.Run is a method to create an already running task_

That's not right, your function can return a task and this task will be executed, see `Run(Func<Task>)` overload

_Task.Start is a method that you shouldn't ever use_
That is beside the point, the method does what is written: schedules the task.

_no good reason_
That is also beside the point, we are not speaking about reasons, actually. You can create tasks without executing them, that is what is written.